# Connect sub model to cell statistics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst

I'm working on a bunch of raster imagery using ArcGIS 10.6.

I have a several sub models consisting of iterations of raster files. Here's one of them, the other do the same but with different parameters:
[image]

And here's my full model.
[image]

The problem is, I can't connect the other value (ssh, sal, etc) into cell statistics.

Is it bug of cell statistics?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be the expected behaviour, the Cell statistics tool takes a **single** list, so this is why you can't connect the multiple outputs.

Turns out there is an easy solution, you feed the outputs of your sub-models into a collects values tool in the master model. This provides a single list to the cell statistics tool.

[image: Example]